# Dont get response from Node server in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

The call is successful but dosent return anything.

Server:

```
export const getTopMovies = async (req, res) => {
console.log("Inside Server")
res.status = 200
res.data = "movies";
return res;
> }
```

Client:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';


const topMovies = () => {

    //const [movies, setMovies] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('http://localhost:8000/movies/getTopMovies')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data.data))
    }, [])
    
    return (
      <div className="max-h-screen w-full fixed h-screen bg-BGColor pt-6">
        <h1 className="text-zinc-50 pt-4 pl-10 text-2xl ">Top Movies</h1>
        <div className="min-w-[82.5%] absolute min-h-[78%] mt-6 ml-10 rounded-3xl bg-BGColorLight1 text-white"> 
        </div>
      </div>
    )
    }
    
  export default topMovies
```

[Log inside server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBAAQ.png)

I tried to return a simple string and log the response but didn't work.

Comment: "*...log the response but didn't work" by "*didn't work*" what did it log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getTopMovies` controller doesn't respond with anything.
You should use the methods from the [`res`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) object:

1. Call the [`status`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status) method with `200` as the argument.
2. Call the [`json`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) method to send the `data: "movies"`.

Modify your `getTopMovies` into:

```js
export const getTopMovies = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Inside Server");
  res.status(200).json({ data: "movies" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the `response.json()`

```
useEffect(() => {
      fetch('http://localhost:8000/movies/getTopMovies')
      .then(response => { return response.json() })
      .then(data => console.log(data.data))
    }, [])
```

Comment: He is already doing that; using Arrow functions if there's one line after the `=>` it's considered as the `return`ed value.